# How to encode resistance change (reed) for Arduino?

Tags: input, resistor

I have a water counter which switches reed on each 10 liters of water. I would like to count these values with Arduino.

I wrote a program which counts changes from analog input and connected counter between `+5V` and analog input. It counts well but I am doubt I connected correctly. Because when reed is opened, then analog input is connected to nothing, while it should be connected to `GND`.

How to implement correct conversion from reed to analog or digital input?

Comment: You could add a large value resistor as a pull-down.

Answer (score 1):

A reed switch is just a button. Treat it as such. Either connect it between a digital input and ground, with a pull-up resistor (internal one would do) or between a digital input and +5V and use a pull-down resistor.